# Not received signal to GPS

Tags: trimble

I have Trimble Juno 3 GPS and I can't go into TerraSync.

The GPS does not receive signals from satellites.

This happened suddenly after I deleted all the files in the file manager and then I turned it off.

Comment: I would suggest a soft reset, http://trl.trimble.com/docushare/dsweb/Get/Document-599015/MGIS_SprtNote_Juno3B_3D_Resetting_0212.pdf... maybe things got hung up somewhere and the GPS can't connect.   Is the GPS connecting?  There is a difference between the GPS not connecting and the GPS not receiving signals.

Answer (score 1):

If TerraSync does not run, you may have deleted some critical file from File Manager.  Or your unit may have spontaneously corrupted the install - that does happen, hopefully only occasionally.

In either case, if turning the Juno off and on again doesn't let TerraSync run, try uninstalling TerraSync from the Juno and reinstalling it.

If TerraSync runs but is unable to connect to the internal GPS receiver, try turning the Juno off, removing the battery, and  leaving it with no battery overnight, then put the battery back and try again.  The SiRF GPS chip in Juno 3 (and other units) sometimes gets in a confused state and removing power for an extended period clears some battery-backed storage.